# How to compute inner angles of polygons

Tags: geometry, angle, polygons

I'm currently implementing an algorithm to split a concave polygon into y-monotone polygons, so I can triangulate those. As I writing this for my own little library, I'm implementing one of the algorithms I saw during a lecture once.

This algorithm needs to known the inner angle between three vertices of the polygon, but I'm not sure how to compute these. For clarification: I'd like to know the angle indicated in red in the following image:

[image]

I would like to solve for the red angle. I've found a formula online that uses atan() but I'm totally not sure how this works and thus I have no idea how to compute this inner angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution. If I loop over my points in a certain order, and I know if the points are cw or ccw connected, I can conclude what is the inner part.

For example. If I loop over my points clockwise:

- If three ordered vertices are connected clockwise, I know that I should take the angle < 90°
- If three ordered vertices are connected counterclockwise, I know that I should take the angle > 90°

Answer (score 0):

Look at vectors $\mathbf u = BA$ and $\mathbf v = BC$. Then
$$ \cos \phi = \frac{\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v}{|\mathbf u||\mathbf v|}$$ where $\phi = \angle ABC$, "$\cdot$" stands for dot product, and $|\mathbf x|$ is the length of vector $\mathbf x$.

Comment: While true, this does not so easily distinguish between the internal and external angles. Just applying acos to get the angle will give a result between 0 and 180 degrees regardless of whether the vertex is convex or concave.

Comment: Exactly, I know how to find the angle between the vectors just fine, it's really the distinction between the two.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  Agree. To get the full picture one can also use the determinant of $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$. Having both $\sin \phi$ and $\cos \phi$  should be sufficient.